# How to fix the error 1001 when i build the CAGL demo with boost?

Tags: c++, boost, c1001

I meet this error when i try to build the CAGL demo.

error C1001 INTERNAL COMPILER ERROR
    I:\ThirdPartLIB\boost_1_61_0\boost\type_traits\common_type.hpp  43  1   AABB_demo

find the code is a part of Boost 1.61.0

```
namespace type_traits_detail

{
template<class T1, class T2, class... T> using common_type_fold = common_type_t<common_type_t<T1, T2>, T...>;
}
```

I search the error and read the notice on MSDN,than i see the project use the /o2. So i change and try different ptions,it doest work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the latest patch release of VC12 if you build boost with VC12(VS 2013).
 see [boost issue](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/11924)